# Processing an eventlog with Pandas - find next match in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am wrangling some data into shape with Pandas. It's mostly going well, but I struggle with the following part.

I have events in a dataframe in the following form. One record for the error and one for the recovery.

```
import pandas as pd

events = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': {0: pd.Timestamp('2017-02-02 09:42:41'),
                                1: pd.Timestamp('2017-02-02 09:42:49'),
                                2: pd.Timestamp('2017-02-02 10:09:07'),
                                3: pd.Timestamp('2017-02-02 10:09:18')},
                      'ERROR': {0: 'CLAMP_ERROR',
                                1: 'CLAMP_ERROR',
                                2: 'CLAMP_ERROR',
                                3: 'CLAMP_ERROR'},
                       'UNIT': {0: 'UNIT004',
                                1: 'UNIT004',
                                2: 'UNIT004',
                                3: 'UNIT004'},
                       'TYPE': {0: 'Unit error',
                                1: 'Recovery',
                                2: 'Unit error',
                                3: 'Recovery'}})
```

**What I'm trying to do**

For each error, find the corresponding recovery and put the DATE of the recovery in to a new column "CLEARED". The correct match can be defined as the next Recovery (in time) with the same UNIT and ERROR.

Desired result:

```
processed = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': {0: Timestamp('2017-02-02 09:42:41')
                                   1: Timestamp('2017-02-02 10:09:07')},
                         'ERROR': {0: 'CLAMP_ERROR',
                                   1: 'CLAMP_ERROR'},
                          'UNIT': {0: 'UNIT004',
                                   1: 'UNIT004'},
                          'TYPE': {0: 'Unit error',
                                   1: 'Unit error'},
                       'CLEARED': {0: Timestamp('2017-02-02 09:42:49'),
                                   1: Timestamp('2017-02-02 10:09:18')}}
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried several different solutions, which will work for the sample I have included here, but with real data the matching does not go as I want.

Splitting the df and merging it with a left join. It matches the wrong recoveries with the errors.

```
errors = events.loc[events.TYPE == 'Unit error']
clears = events.loc[events.TYPE == 'Recovery']

processed = pd.merge(errors, clears, how='left', on=['ERROR', 'UNIT'])
```

Another solution I tried was to sort the dataframe, create new columns with the offset from the next row:

```
events.sort_values('UNIT', 'DATE')

events['nTYPE'] = events['TYPE'].shift(-1)
events['nDATE'] = events['DATE'].shift(-1)
events['nUNIT'] = events['UNIT'].shift(-1)
events['nERROR'] = events['ERROR'].shift(-1)
```

This would work perfectly if all the errors and recoveries always came in pairs.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how I can solve or approach this.

Comment: I suspect the `ROBOT` is a left-over from reducing the example?

Comment: Is it always clear that there is a recover for an error before the next error appears?

Comment: @languitar - Regarding `ROBOT`, yes - it should be `UNIT`. I have updated my post.

Comment: @languitar - No, it is not always clear that a recover will be present before the next error appears. Two different errors can overlap on the same unit. The following scenario is possible:

Error 1
Error 2
Recovery error 2
Recovery error 1

It is also possible that the recovery never happens.

Comment: But it will always be a distinct error type in that case?

Comment: The error type will not necessarily be distinct. It can an error with the same ERROR type as the majority of other errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess:

```
events = events.sort_values(['UNIT', 'ERROR', 'DATE'])
shifted = events.shift(-1)
shifted['Use'] = (events.ERROR == shifted.ERROR) & (events.UNIT == shifted.UNIT) & (shifted.TYPE == 'Recovery')
events['CLEARED'] = shifted.apply(lambda x: x['DATE'] if x['Use'] else None, axis=1)
```

Comment: I tested this on the entire data set, and it handled all the exceptions flawlessly. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Good to hear. I wasn't sure whether this works reliably ;-)